# Can I set up an animation on an arbitrary UIView variable?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, core-animation

In the past, I have used the `UIView` animation stuff well as long as I'm working on attributes that are already part of the UIKit frameworks.

Lately, I have created a custom UIView control that displays some calendar/scheduling behavior and supports infinite scroll. What controls the scroll position is a simple NSDate variable that have I have declared as such:

```
var position = NSDate().mondayMorning() {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

As long as that `position` changes, things just work. It was even simple to set up the scrolling with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
struct StartState { static var position:NSDate = NSDate() }
switch pan.state {
case .Began:
    StartState.position = self.position
case .Changed:
    let translation = pan.translationInView(self).y
    self.position = StartState.position - ((7 * 24).hours / self.cellWidth * translation)
case .Cancelled:
    self.position = StartState.position
default:
    break
}
```

The tricky part comes when I try to implement a decal motion at the `.Ended` case. Ideally, I would like to some sort of `UIView.animationWithDuration(... .CurveEaseOut)` incantation, but despite much trial and error, I got nothing to work. In the past, I have been able to do my own custom stuff like that, but in those cases, I was messing with layout, so I would just make my animation block be a `layoutIfNeeded`, but in this case, I want to modify this NSDate value along a curve and drive the subsequent display updates. Unable to find something that worked, I just resorted to high school physics and did my own:

```
case .Ended:
    let translation = pan.translationInView(self).y
    let v = pan.velocityInView(self).y
    let a:CGFloat = -4000.0 // 4 pixels/millisecond, recommended on gavedev
    let travelTime = (v / a).abs.seconds
    let started = NSDate()
    let timer = Timer()
    timer.interval = 40.milliseconds
    timer.tick = {
        let elapsed = NSDate() - started
        if elapsed >= travelTime {
            timer.stop()
        }
        else {
            let decelDisplacement = (v.abs * CGFloat(elapsed.seconds.magnitude) + (a * 0.5 * CGFloat(elapsed.seconds.magnitude.squared))) * v.sign
            self.position = StartState.position - ((7 * 24).hours / self.cellWidth * (translation + decelDisplacement))
        }
    }
    timer.start()
```

This works. But if it were possible to leverage the CoreAnimation stuff here, I would like to. Is there a middle ground where I can do this? Or is the animation stuff all in or all out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across a way for doing this with UIView animation APIs without involving CoreAnimation. You certainly can with CoreAnimation and Apple provides some [nice example code for this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2284/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014302-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). There's also [an objc.io article about this topic](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animating-custom-layer-properties/).

I did find [this solution](https://github.com/Tricertops/UIView-AnimatedProperty) that works for UIView animations, but it actually [underneath accomplishes this behaviour using CoreAnimation](https://github.com/Tricertops/UIView-AnimatedProperty/blob/master/Sources/UIView%2BAnimatedProperty.m#L253) as is also suggested in the README.